# What is the difference between 2'b0 and 2'd0?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, register-transfer-level, vlsi

I was tying a port to zero in my design.  What is the difference between `2'b0` and `2'd0` in Verilog?

What does `b` and `d` actually mean?

Answer (score 5):

`b` and `d` are the base radix of the numeric literal; *binary* and *decimial* respectively. They are equivalent values in your case. In both literals, you are specifying 2-bit width values, with both bits having a '0' value. `2'b11` and `2'd3` would also be equivalent, with both bits having a '1' value.

Note that you can also write `'0` which is a fill literal that expands to the width of the port.